# Why $I=\left\{p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}\left[X\right]:2\mid p(0)\right\}$ is not a principal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193031/confusion-between-principal-ideal-and-ideal) but I still do not understand:

> What is the difference between ideal and principal ideal?

At my homework I had to prove to things about $I=\left\{p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}\left[X\right]:2\mid p(0)\right\}$:
1. That $I$ is an ideal. I prove it...
2. That $I$ is **not** a principal ideal.

Now how can I prove 2.? Why $I$ isn't a principal ideal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a comment but it is too long for that. I am going to show that $ I= (2,x)$ is not principal. Suppose to the contrary that $I$ is principal so there would be $f \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ such that $I = (f)$. Since $2 \in I$ we have $2 \in (f)$ and hence there is a polynomial $g$ such that $2 = fg$. This means that $f$ is a constant polynomial lets say $m$. But on the other hand $x\in I$ and hence $x \in (f)$ therefore there is a polynomial $h$ such that $x = mh$ if we compare the coefficients of $x$ we get that $m = 1$ which means that $(f)$ (and hence $I$) is equal the whole ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. A contradiction. Pleaes let me know if you need some more explanation.

Comment: You explain very well. If there be questions I'll ask you! Thank you!

Comment: So, if I'm understand it right, if there is element at $I$ that makes all the ring is shows that $I$ is not principal, I'm right?

Answer (score 5):

Can you show your ideal equals $(2,X)$? Can you show that cannot be principal? *Hint* If it were, say $(p)=(2,X)$ then we'd have $p\mid 2$ and $p\mid X$.

*What is the difference between ideal and principal ideal?*

If $R$ is a ring, a (double sided) ideal $I$ of $R$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $R$ that is closed under multiplication by elements of $R$ both on the right and on the left, that is, $RI=\{ri:r\in R,i\in I\}$ and $IR=\{ir:r\in R,i\in I\}$ are both contained in $I$.

A principal ideal is one that is generated by single element of your ring, that is, it consists of all $R$ multiples of a fixed element, for example $2\Bbb Z=\{2n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is a principal ideal in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: What is $(2,X)$? (I don't this sign...) Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman The ideal generated by $2$ and $X$.

Comment: What makes it principal? I think that I didn't understand the definition...

Comment: @YoavFridman You want to show it is **not** principal, don't you?

Comment: I know that $\left<2\right>$ is ideal... I don't understand what is ideal that generated by $2$ and $X$...

Comment: @YoavFridman If you know what it means for an ideal to not be principal it's important you know how to *notate* such ideals. The notation $(a_1,a_2,\cdots)$ means the set of all $R$-coefficient combinations of the elements $a_1,a_2,\cdots$.

Comment: Yes, but what is the definition of **principal**, I think this is what I don't understand...

Comment: @YoavFridman if that is the problem, then you should look up the definition where you got the problem from.

Comment: @anon, this is what I don't know/understand: "what it means for an ideal to not be principal"....

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I saw the definition but I still not understand, this is why I'm asking you....

Comment: @YoavFridman If you read the definition and don't understand it, then you need to formulate precisely what it is about it you don't understand, or there is no way anyone can help you.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, can you give me a link to place that shows the definition **with** examples?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, Thank you for your edit, but how can I prove that $I$ is not made by a single element?

Comment: @YoavFridman I added something.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, but how can I show it? what is the way to prove that is not principal?

Comment: By example? why $(2,X)$ not makes $I$?

Comment: @YoavFridman I am saying $(2,X)$ equals $I$. Can you try to be clearer?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, yes, sorry, I try to understand how can I show that $I$ is not principle, you say that $(2,X)$ equals $I$, so why $I$ is **not** principle??

Comment: @YoavFridman I have given you a hint in the answer.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I'm confuse - If $(2,X)=I$ so $(2,X)$ makes $I$ so $(2,X)$ is principle, no??

Comment: @YoavFridman Please try to understand what a principal ideal is.

Comment: @anon, I'm try, but still I think I miss something at the definition that is not clear to me... I still can't understand why $(2,X)$ shows as that $I$ is not principal...

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, can you add please one more example at your answer, **but** that example will of something that is not principal? that I will see an opposite example? Thank you!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, how can I show that something is not a principal ideal? example is enough? Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman You might want to know that your ideal is also a maximal ideal.

Comment: @RobertM, why $I$ is maximal? and how does it helps me to prove that $I$ is not principal?

Comment: @YoavFridman You don't need maximality of $I$. That was only an extra information about $I$. Meanwhile $I$ is maximal because when you divide $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ by $I$ you get $\Bbb{Z}_2$ which is a field. But if you are not familiar with this concept just ignore my comments.

Comment: @RobertM, oh, thank you! I know what is maximal ideal, but I didn't understand how does it helps me to prove is not principal...
sorry. is because I really want to understand how to prove this...

Comment: @Yoav: ${\bf Z}[X]$ is two-dimensional (since $\bf Z$ is one-dimensional and taking polynomials adds a dimension). Maximal ideals correspond to points, hence have dimension zero. Principal ideals on the other are generated by a single element, hence correspond to one-dimensional curves. This is an intuition for why a maximal ideal is not principal (it would be a full proof in ${\bf C}[X, Y]$, say, since maximal ideals correspond to points in $\bf C$ and principal ideals to curves). But these are just aside comments, you have complete answer given, so try to understand it before asking more.