# Whats avoid from ideal to be principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

At [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629950/why-i-left-px-in-mathbbz-leftx-right2-mid-p0-right-is-not-a-prin#629954) I asked about specific one...

But I think that I don't understand the basic:

> If I have an ideal $I$, what avoid it to be principal?

I think that I really need a good example of some ideal $I$ that is **not**(!!) principal.

At all the books and the examples I saw that $\left<m\right>=m\cdot \mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal, but I look for an opposite example, i.e. an ideal that is **not** principal and why this ideal is not principal...

I open another Q, because I really want to understand it but not via my example...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You will not find an example in $\mathbb{Z}$, since all of its ideals are principal.

Since you don't like $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, consider the other simple example, $k[X,Y]$, where $k$ is any field.

Take the set of elements with zero constant term.  This is an ideal generated by $X$ and $Y$.  But it's not principal.  Why?  Because if it were generated by a polynomial $p(X,Y)$, then $p(X,Y)$ would have to be a factor of $X$, and also a factor of $Y$.  The only such polynomials are the non-zero constants, which don't belong to our ideal.

Intuitively, we don't expect the ideal generated by $X$ and $Y$ to be principal, because $X$ and $Y$ are abstract symbols with no relation between them.

Comment: What is $k[X,Y]$?

Comment: @YoavFridman The polynomial ring in two variables over $k$.  $k$ could be $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ or anything; it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Oh, we didn't learn it yet...:-).
B.T.W, I'm ok with $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ LOL, I just want general example...

Comment: @YoavFridman This is the most general example there is, since we've just taken a general ring with two abstract symbols and no relationship between them.  Any other example will look pretty much like this—for instance, in your $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ example, we have $Y=2$...

Comment: @YoavFridman Also, you know about polynomial rings in two variables as long as you know about polynomial rings in one variable, since $k[X,Y] = (k[X])[Y] = (k[Y])[X]$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the ideal $(x,y) \subset k[x,y]$.

By definition an ideal is principal iff there's an element $a \in I$ such that $I=(a)$

Now, our ideal $(x,y)$ is not principal. Suppose there's a polynomial $P(x,y)$ such that $(x,y)=(P(x,y))$, then there must exist polynomials $R(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ such than $x=P(x,y)R(x,y)$ and $y=P(x,y)Q(x,y)$.

Now we obtain, looking at the degrees of $P$ and $R$ in the variables $x$ and $y$ that:

- $deg_xP+deg_xR=deg_xx=1$
- $deg_yP+deg_yR=deg_yx=0$

This implies:

- $deg_yP=deg_yR=0$, follows that $P$ and $R$ are constant in $y$ and then have the only variable $x$
- Two ptions about the degree in x: $deg_xP=1$ and $deg_xR=0$ or $deg_xP=0$ and $deg_xR=1$

Now we come to an absurd in a lot of ways, for exaple:
*If $P$ generates $(x,y)$ and it is a polynomial in the only variable $x$, how can be $y$ be a multiple of $P$?*

Comment: Can you explain more please? Thank you!!

Comment: I've edited. I hope now I'm more clear